# Run two scripts in separate directories, in parallel, and in foreground

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, shell, unix, reactjs

**Context:** I'm trying to write a bash function to make my life incrementally more convenient, but I don't think the goal is possible. I'm hoping I can get someone to Confirm/Deny my suspicion:

**Goal/Question:** Make a shell function that will start a rails server in one directory and start up react in another, but without opening two terminal tabs and running the commands separately. (*Is this possible?*)

**Attempted:**

```
function run_project(){
  (cd [RAILS_PROJ_DIR] && exec rails server) && (cd [REACT_PROJ_DIR] && exec yarn start)
}
```

**Issues:** Function doesn't work because the second command waits for the first to finish successfully. But if I can somehow get both to run successfully, wouldn't one run in the background (which prevents me from viewing log output)?

*UPDATE:*

Thanks for responses, all.  I got close to what I wanted with a little modification, but it's a bit of a square peg solution for a round hole:

`function run_project(){
(cd [RAILS_PROJ_DIR] && exec rails server &) && (cd [REACT_PROJ_DIR] && exec yarn start &)
}`

As others have pointed out, mixing both log outputs isn't ideal, and this also seems to prevent `pry` from working.  Foreman is probably the real way to go.  Marking as accepted answer.

Comment: There is only one "foreground". You can't run two processes in the foreground. Of course you could run two processes in the background, and writing a special "collector" program which would grab the output of those processes and displays it in some interleaved way - but isn't this going to be confusing? Maybe something like [multitail](https://linux.die.net/man/1/multitail) would better suit your requirements.

Comment: Would you still like to read both the logs together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is something like `Foreman`:

https://github.com/ddollar/foreman

http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html

You can list all your commands in using a Procfile like so:

Procfile.dev:

```
web: bundle exec rails server
yarn: exec yarn start
```

And then simply run `foreman start` in your command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can start commands in the background via shell by using an '&'.

```
(cd /some/directory; ./command1 -a arg) >output.txt 2>&1 &
(cd /some/other/directory; ./command2 -a other_arg) >output2.txt 2>&1 &
```

That will capture the output for each command to a file which you can then use 'tail -f' to keep an eye on.

Note that if you logout before the commands complete, they may get killed.  If you want to prevent that behavior use the 'nohup' command when you launch them.

Once the commands are running, use the 'jobs' command to see them listed at which point you can bring either one to the foreground using the 'fg' command.  While the command is in the foreground, use ^Z to stop it and then type 'bg' to send it to the background.

Not exactly what you're looking for but you cannot have two jobs in the foreground at the same time. You can, however, switch between them using basic job control commands.

```
Jamess-MacBook:bin jj$ (while [ 1 ]; do echo 'job 1'; sleep 3; done) >/tmp/job1.out 2>&1 &
[1] 3735
Jamess-MacBook:bin jj$ (while [ 1 ]; do echo 'job 2'; sleep 3; done) >/tmp/job2.out 2>&1 &
[2] 3740
Jamess-MacBook:bin jj$ tail -f /tmp/job
job1.out  job2.out
Jamess-MacBook:bin jj$ tail -f /tmp/job?.out

==> /tmp/job1.out <==
job 1
job 1
job 1
job 1
job 1
job 1
job 1

==> /tmp/job2.out <==
job 2
job 2
job 2
job 2

==> /tmp/job1.out <==
job 1
^C
Jamess-MacBook:bin jj$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 ( while [ 1 ]; do
    echo 'job 1'; sleep 3;
done ) > /tmp/job1.out 2>&1 &
[2]+  Running                 ( while [ 1 ]; do
    echo 'job 2'; sleep 3;
done ) > /tmp/job2.out 2>&1 &
Jamess-MacBook:bin jj$ fg %1
( while [ 1 ]; do
    echo 'job 1'; sleep 3;
done ) > /tmp/job1.out 2>&1
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ( while [ 1 ]; do
echo 'job 1'; sleep 3;
done ) > /tmp/job1.out 2>&1
Jamess-MacBook:bin jj$ bg
[1]+ ( while [ 1 ]; do
    echo 'job 1'; sleep 3;
done ) > /tmp/job1.out 2>&1 &
Jamess-MacBook:bin jj$
Jamess-MacBook:bin jj$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 ( while [ 1 ]; do
    echo 'job 1'; sleep 3;
done ) > /tmp/job1.out 2>&1 &
[2]+  Running                 ( while [ 1 ]; do
    echo 'job 2'; sleep 3;
done ) > /tmp/job2.out 2>&1 &
Jamess-MacBook:bin jj$ kill %1
Jamess-MacBook:bin jj$ kill %2
[1]-  Terminated: 15          ( while [ 1 ]; do
    echo 'job 1'; sleep 3;
done ) > /tmp/job1.out 2>&1
Jamess-MacBook:bin jj$ jobs
[2]+  Terminated: 15          ( while [ 1 ]; do
    echo 'job 2'; sleep 3;
done ) > /tmp/job2.out 2>&1
Jamess-MacBook:bin jj$ jobs
Jamess-MacBook:bin jj$
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the second `&&` with `&`.

Indeed, the command to the left of `&` will run in background but you will be able to see its output, albeit intermixed with the other command's output.